# Update Json array value in C#

Tags: json

I have the below json. You can see for 'Parrot' there is no Image. How can I modify the Image property to a default url, if it is null?

```
  {
       "Items":[
          {
             "Name":"Lion",
             "Image":"https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/cfperron/cats/images/cat8.jpg",
             "Animal":"Cats"
          },
          {
              "Name":"Parrot",
             "Image":"",
             "Animal":"Birds"
          }
       ]
    }
```

Expected Output:

```
  {
       "Items":[
          {
             "Name":"Lion",
             "Image":"https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/cfperron/cats/images/cat8.jpg",
             "Animal":"Cats"
          },
          {
              "Name":"Parrot",
             "Image":"https://defaultImage.jpg",
             "Animal":"Birds"
          }
       ]
    }
```

Comment: You write the JSON? you read it?

Comment: Basically read the json, edit the value of Jrray and write into a new json

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialize the json, find the field you want to change, change is and serialize it back.

```
     public class Item
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Image { get; set; }
            public string Animal { get; set; }
        }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string orgJson = "{\"Items\":[{\"Name\":\"Lion\", \"Image\":\"https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/cfperron/cats/images/cat8.jpg\", \"Animal\":\"Cats\" }, {\"Name\":\"Parrot\",\"Image\":\"\",\"Animal\":\"Birds\"}]}";
        Root rt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(orgJson);
        for (int i =0; i < rt.Items.Count ;i++)
        {
            if (rt.Items[i].Image.Equals(""))
            {
                rt.Items[i].Image = "https://defaultImage.jpg";
            }
        }
        string newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rt);
    }
}
```